# Can I use a 200A main circuit breaker panel as a 100A subpanel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

**Short version:**
Can I use a 200A MCB panel as a 100A subpanel?  Can I leave the 200A large-format breaker in the subpanel, or would I have to remove the 200A breaker and convert it to a MLO (obviously, there would be a 100A breaker in the main panel).

**Longer version:**
I currently have 200A service running into my single, 200A, 30-breaker, main circuit breaker panel.  I'm running out of breaker slots, and need to add on a sub panel.  I've run the calcs for my power loads (the energy.gov calculator that crunches the NEC formulae), and I'm at about 175A.  I don't think there's a reason to upgrade my residential service to 400A just yet, but who knows what new power-hungry toys humanity is going to need 20 years from now.  If I had 2 200A MCBs, if/when I upgrade, I'd be most of the way there with the two panels ready for new feeders.

I'd of course float my neutrals, and install a separate grounding bar in the subpanel.

A 125A MLO panel and cover is roughly $150.  A 200A MCB is roughly $250.  If it meets Code, $100 for me is worth it for a bit of future-proofing.

Comment: As long as the the feed breaker(in main panel) is at or less than the sub panel's rating it is good.  I think the breaker in sub panel must equal or be larger, so feeding a 200 amp breaker/panel from a 40 amp breaker is good(if you wanted).  The sub panel's breaker basically becomes a disconnect use.  Usually it is recommended to go big(200 amps) for sub panels, even if never expected to use that much.

Comment: The savings of using a 100A panel instead of a 200A panel are not worth it for the average DIYer IMHO. You can always use a smaller feed breaker and even obtain a smaller main breaker if you want. But a higher rate panel should cost under $100 more if you're already doing the work. Replacing it later with a bigger one is more heartache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine. Nobody cares if a subpanel (in the same building) has a completely superfluous main breaker.  And for a 100A feeder, it's always better to use a 200A subpanel with plenty of spaces than a 100A subpanel with barely enough spaces.

> who knows what new power-hungry toys humanity is going to need 20 years from now.

Well right now, the wind is actually blowing in the opposite direction, as appliances only get more efficient, and [energy management](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/277803/im-hearing-about-load-sheds-aka-evems-and-the-devices-differ-whats-that-abou) is starting to exist.

Technology Connections [has a 2-part series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVLLNjSLJTQ) on this.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly could use the 200A as is (and in this case should). The breaker feeding the panel has to be equal or smaller than the rating of the sub-panel, and breaker in the subpanel can remain even if oversized. The wire has to be rated large enough for the breaker feeding the sub-panel.

If it's in the same building you don't even need a main breaker in the sub-panel. If it's in a detached building the breaker satisfies the disconnect requiement, even if oversized since the requirement is  just for a disconnect as overcurrent protection is provided in the main panel.

Comment: I considered an MLO for the subpanel - in fact that's what I was going to go with first.  From my quick Google searching, anything reasonably priced maxes out at 125A for a MLO - at least for QO, which was the brand I want to go with. Thanks for the comment!