Can I connect a 100 amp sub panel to a main that is 275 feet away?
Can I connect a 100 amp sub panel to a 100 amp main that is 275 feet away?  I am wanting to run electricity to an outbuilding. What size wire should be used?  I will be burying the cable in plastic conduit as well, what size conduit would I be using?

You only have 100 amps total,  another 100amp panel will not give an extra 100 amps, but take away from the main.  Unless using gas for all heating devices, a 100 amps does leave much extra in a modem house.

If this is for EV charging, look into EVEMS. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/277803/im-hearing-about-load-sheds-aka-evems-and-the-devices-differ-whats-that-abou
